# Where can I get RCX 1.0 software?

Tags: software, rcx

We've got a LEGO RCX 1.0 without any Software.
I've installed the USB IR Tower, what should I do now?

I've downloaded the EV3 Software from the LEGO homepage and thought I could use this, but I don't know how.

Can you tell me, how my son could play with it?

Answer (score 2):

The EV3 software is not backwards compatible with RCX 1.0.

You will need to install the software from the CD-ROM that would have come with your set. If you do decide to [purchase one online](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?itemID=44442), you can do so from a 3rd party marketplace such as Bricklink.

Be sure to install the correct version of the CD-ROM (RCX 1.0) and check to see if your operating system is compatible with the software.

Comment: thank you for your answer!
I´ll see I´ve to get the CD-Rom...at first I´ll look for it in an Europe shop, if I find one. Thaks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **any** version of the original Robotics Instruction Set (RIS) with this brick: 1.0, 1.5, or 2.0. There is also one release of software from LEGO Education that was the last that supported the RCX brick, but I don't know much about that. Any of these will work with the brick you have.

These releases are Windows only, AFAIK. If you don't run Windows, your biggest hurdle will be getting a Windows VM working with the serial or USB IR tower.

It will upload the latest firmware to the brick, so even if your brick says "1.0" on it, it will accept any version of the bundled (or supplied by you) firmware. That is, firmware versions 3.09, 3.28, 3.32 will all work on the original RCX 1.0.

So, my advice is to find a copy of RIS 2.0 for your son. You should be able to find it on eBay or Bricklink.

I see there is [another answer that attempts to help you find the RIS 2.0](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4455/3971) package.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of the LEGO RIS software, you can use [BricxCC](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/) to write programs for the RCX.

It's not graphical as the LEGO software but is intended to teach programming instead of drawing blocks on screen.

It works well under Wine if you're using Linux.

Comment: Note that the related questions and answers talk about how RIS under WINE has problems with USB towers, which the OP specifically uses.